# How to see another merged branch's commits when the start point is not the ancestor?

Tags: git, branch, commit

I'm using a vim plugin manager `neobundle`, there is a feature which shows the updates of plugins (for git, shows the commit messages between two git pull update).

Here is the situation, Use `git log --graph {old_rev}..{new_rev}` can check out the commit messages between the this update and the previous update. But here is the problem, when the `{old_rev}` is an a revision after the merged branch's ancestor, then the `git log --graph` will not show commit message in that merged branch.

Here are some screenshots for comparing:

[tig] here is the all commit message history from program tig.
[from tig http://ompldr.org/vZnAwZg](http://ompldr.org/vZnAwZg)

[neobundle] here is the output from vim plugin manager neobundle.
[from neobundle http://ompldr.org/vZnAwZw](http://ompldr.org/vZnAwZw)

[it should be like this]here is the expected output which has omitted branch commit message.
[expected output http://ompldr.org/vZnAwaA](http://ompldr.org/vZnAwaA)

The command used in plugin neobundle is:
`git log {old_rev}..{new_rev} --graph --pretty=format:'%h [%cr] %s'`

I discussed this with author of this plugin at here:
https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim/issues/24

So how to let command can show the merged branch's commit messages too ?

- if you can archive this with other commands, it's ok too.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, use command `git log {old_rev}^..{new_rev} --graph --pretty=format:'%h [%cr] %s'` by adding `^` to get the ancestor.